# Teams Messaging Extensions Config Auth

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams

I created a  Message extension, using the sample,

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config

and I am following this doc for authentication,

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/add-authentication#:~:text=If%20your%20service%20requires%20user,can%20use%20the%20messaging%20extension.&text=User%20issues%20a%20query%2C%20or,inspecting%20the%20Teams%20user%20ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/add-authentication#:%7E:text=If%20your%20service%20requires%20user,can%20use%20the%20messaging%20extension.&text=User%20issues%20a%20query%2C%20or,inspecting%20the%20Teams%20user%20ID).

Technology Used :- Node Js

**The issue I am facing is, I am unable to open the auth webpage when installing the Message extension in teams, It directly open the message extension window instead of web page.**

```
        // The user has requested the Messaging Extension Configuration page settings url.
        const userSettings = await this.userConfigurationProperty.get(context, '');
        const escapedSettings = userSettings ? querystring.escape(userSettings) : '';

// I am able to reach here, but that url which is returning is not opening.

        return {
            composeExtension: {
                type: 'config',
                suggestedActions: {
                    actions: [
                        {
                            type: ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                            value: `${process.env.SiteUrl}/public/searchSettings.html?settings=${escapedSettings}`
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

In manifest file, I passed the valid url as mentioned in document, but still that auth page is not opening.

If you have any reference or any document related to this, please share.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is message extension sample using node.js and including SSO: https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples/msgext-graph-action-docreview

Comment: I am doing the same as above example, I quite figure it out how to authenticate in message extension, thanks. but now I am getting an another error, when i click on the link, generated by this function --> **context.adapter.getSignInLink(context, this.connectionName),**

{
  "error": {
    "code": "ServiceError",
    "message": "An error occured while retrieving the signin link"
  }
}